# PHP - loop button and input in form

Tags: php, forms, loops, post, foreach

I wanted create firm list (from sql) and buttons to delete. It should looks like:

```
 ------------------------------
 |name_firm1   'delete_button'|
 |name_firm2   'delete_button'|
 |name_firm3   'delete_button'|
 ------------------------------
```

i created form (here i removed css elements for you):

```
echo '<form method="post" name="remove_firm_to_targs" action="">';

         while($saf = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_added_firm)) 
         {
            $query = mysql_query ("SELECT id_firm, name_firm FROM firms WHERE id_firm ='".$saf['id_firm']."'");
            $q = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

            <input type="hidden" name="id_firm[]" value="'.$q['id_firmy'].'" />
            <div> '.$q['name_firm'].' </div>
            <div><input type="submit" id="button" value="delete firm" name="remove_firm_to_targ"/></div></div>';
        }
echo '</form>';
```

I can't $_post id_firm from hidden input.
Here is code:

```
if(isset($_POST['remove_firm_to_targ'])) {
    $id_targ = $_GET['id']; 

    $id_firmy = array();
    foreach ($_POST['id_firm'] as $idid)
    {
        $id_firm[] = array ('idid' => $idid);
    }

    mysql_query ("DELETE FROM firm_to_targ WHERE id_firm = '".$id_firm.' && id_targ = '".$id_targ."'");
}
```

I change this code many times so now it has nosense.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` use instead [PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) BTW you miss a doublequote `"` in your `Delete query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form should be like this:
I put the id of the firm into delete button value.

```
while($saf = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_added_firm))
{
echo '<form method="post" name="remove_firm_to_targs" action="">';

    $query = mysql_query ("SELECT id_firm, name_firm FROM firms WHERE id_firm ='".$saf['id_firm']."'");
$q = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

<div> '.$q['name_firm'].' </div>
<div><input type="submit" id="button" value="DELETE" name="remove_firm_to_targ"/></div></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="delete_this" value="'.$q['id_firmy'].'">
    ';

    echo '</form>';
}
```

So when you submit the button for the firm, it will delete the firm which has id on delete button value's:

```
if(isset($_POST['remove_firm_to_targ'])) {
$id_targ = $_GET['id'];

mysql_query ("DELETE FROM firm_to_targ WHERE id_firm = '".$_POST['delete_this'].' && id_targ = '".$id_targ."'");
}
```

Comment: I didnt know this is so easy :) It worked but now how i can change value of each button? i mean, the value which is shown on the button:) I dont want have  for ex. '23' on button :)

Comment: HA! i knew it that hidden input must be there :) thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

```
while($saf = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_added_firm)) { 
    $query = mysql_query ("SELECT id_firm, 
             name_firm FROM firms WHERE id_firm ='".$saf['id_firm']."'"); 
        $q = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 
<div> '.$q['name_firm'].' </div> 
<a href="delete.php?id=$q['name']</div>'; 
 } 
 echo '</form>';
```

in ur case

Comment: Please format your answer better and add a description of *how* this addresses the original question